# The action 'new' could not be found for DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, rspec, devise

Set up Authentication with AngularJS and Ruby on Rails, use gem devise_token_auth. But when run the test with rspec have the same error

Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
       The action 'new' could not be found for DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController

I saw different sites but everyone try to do new controller for example: class Devise::SessionsController < ApplicationController
but this didn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

Going purely from the error you supplied,

create a sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

def new
end

end
```

You can do this either manually or run:

```
rails generate devise:controllers [scope]
```

from within your app directory in the terminal. (Replace scope with the model devise interacts with, e.g user).

Also, give this a read.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: I did as you wrote, but  when  run rspec, I have same error Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
       The action 'new' could not be found for DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController    Maybe you can look my code on github?